# can't show the scrollview indicator in a scrollview

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

This is my ViewController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.imageView.image = self.image;
    self.scrollView.contentSize = self.imageView.image.size;
    self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.imageView.image.size.width, self.imageView.image.size.height);   
    self.title = [self.photo objectForKey:FLICKR_PHOTO_TITLE];
    self.scrollView.delegate = self;
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.scrollView flashScrollIndicators];
    self.scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = YES;
}
```

But it didn't show anything. 
I already checked out several same questions in here and tried all the possible solutions, but none worked.

Comment: Have you added it to the view? [self.view addsubview:self.scrollview]?

Comment: I already tried [self.view addsubview:self.scrollview] but didn't work.

Comment: Arya: do you mean this one:self.scrollView.contentSize = self.imageView.image.size; I add it in the above.

Comment: you also need to add your image view to scrollview. so .. [self.scrollview addSubview: self.imageView]; [self.view addSubview:self.scrollView];

Comment: i just tried that in viewDidLoad,but still didn't work.

Comment: Also, i don't think this will make a difference cause i already add the imageview under a view and then embed in a scroll view inside a imageview in the storyboard,right?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread but I came across it so...

The horizontal or vertical scroll view indicators only show when the content is larger than the scroll view. So if your full image is already showing then no indicators.